# How to use Codes from Github in my application

Tags: android, github, widget

Hi iam newbie to android and  i always being confused that how can i use code from github into my app .most of the time i notices that some of the task in our app are beautifully designed by some one in github for example now days iam developing app which need to crop image after selection from gallery and i found this code sample from github [Crop Image](https://gist.github.com/pookie13/1ad1623bec8d7ee76b66) but i dont know how to use this code in my app, like what is *dependencies* of that code ,which method can we override to get the result.And also the from Where dose that xml widget appears,and how its made. Below example from same code.

```
<com.goparties.gpuser.util.CropImageView
    android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/black_trans"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    app:cropMode="circle"
    app:frameColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:frameStrokeWeight="1dp"
    app:guideColor="@color/orange"
    app:guideShowMode="show_on_touch"
    app:guideStrokeWeight="1dp"
    app:handleColor="@color/orange"
    app:handleShowMode="show_always"
    app:handleSize="8dp"
    app:minFrameSize="100dp"
    app:overlayColor="@color/uncrop_color"
    app:touchPadding="8dp" />
```

Please give some suggestions how can we use that codes in my app its 2 days now iam looking for way to implement this also the *gradle dependencies* of above code is missing.

Comment: find the jar file of the git repository download it and paste it in your project's libs folder then sync it

Comment: @Praveen unable to locate jar file for this code [Crop Image](https://gist.github.com/pookie13/1ad1623bec8d7ee76b66)

Comment: Well this link is not of  github repository from where you can find path of gradle dependencies ..in readme.md. You can Try to  copy& paste code directly in your project.

Comment: @rachit3dev Infact, U have found a code which is  shared..among peers...its not a github repository..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more information about gists, see https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/

Like it says there, each gist is a repo, and you can fork it, etc.
You can download the gist with the 'download zip' button.

The gist you mentioned is just someone 'sharing some code' and it is not a turnkey 'library' you can just plug in to your project.  One way to use that code would be to copy/paste it into your android project as you see fit and it will be up to you to figure out, by following the author's shared sample code as a guide, how to use it or adapt it and whether it will work for your needs.

To address your more general question (how to use code from github) - generally the readme.md will have some instructions, for cases where the author is trying to publish a general-purpose library for you to use.

Comment: Good to know,also read somewhere that there is gradle dependencies of every library,once we put it in build.gradle file and sync it, it downloads the entire library and further we can override methods , use xml widgets etc . want to know it that true???

Comment: @rachit3dev Yes,it all true,happy to know you have ..understood all the things about github , gist..happy coding!!! buddy...